# Django ORM annotate on foreign key query

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 3 models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(
        max_length=2000,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None
    )

class QuestionSession(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=500, default=None, null=True, blank=True
    )
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='sessions',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None
    )

class Question(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    question_session = models.ForeignKey(
        QuestionSession,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='questions',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None
    )
```

As you can see, Project contains Sessions, Session contains questions.
What I'm trying to achieve is I wanna fetch a single Project with sessions and number of questions in them. I can do it easily with 2 different queries but I cannot do it in 1 query.

My serializers:

```
class SingleProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sessions = MinifiedSessionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'sessions'
        ]

class MinifiedSessionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions_number = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = QuestionSession
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'questions_number'
        ]
```

I used to grab sessions in a single query like this:

```
Project.objects.get(id=project_id).sessions.annotate(questions_number=Count('questions'))
```

But how to do it now? I need to fetch the project first and then annotate on sessions. I have no idea how to do it. I need a query like this:

```
Project.objects.filter(pk=project_id).annotate(sessions__questions_number=Count('sessions__questions'))
```

Comment: `prefetch_related()` is your friend. It will perform one single additional query to get all of the sessions and you can hand it a queryset containing sessions with annotated number-of-questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible through Django ORM. The only solution which I can think of is changing the way on how you ask for the data:

```
sessions = QuestionSession.objects.filter(project_id=project_id).select_related('project').annotate(questions_number=Count('questions'))
project = sessions[0].project
```

That would end up in a single query, but I assume you want to pass this `project` instance down to the DRF serializer. In such case the `project` knows nothing about prefetched sessions, so it would need to be handled separately. Additionally there is an issue when particular project has no associated sessions - `sessions[0].project` would raise exception. To keep the code clean I would probably stay with yours current approach (but then - the issue remains unresolved to keep everything in one db hit).